# apache http authentication different for site root and subfolder

Tags: apache, authentication

in a simple document system, the directory structure looks like this:

```
root
  files1
  files2
```

I need to authorize all authenticated users to root, and only one specific user per subfolder:

```
root > authorized: user1, user2
  files1 > authorized: user1
  files2 > authorized: user2
```

Using HTTP authentication in Apache Httpd, which could be the best way to obtain this?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'm currently using as follows.
In root:
.htpasswd
.htgroup with group users:user1 user2
.htaccess:

```
AuthName "Please enter user and password"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /full/path/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /full/path/.htgroup
<Limit GET POST>
require group users
</Limit>
```

In each subdirectory, a .htaccess like this:

```
AuthName "Please enter user and password"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/root/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /full/path/to/root/.htgroup
<Limit GET POST>
require user valid-user
</Limit>
```

Comment: I further simplified the subfolders .htaccess, removing the "authxxx" directives, and keeping only <Limit> ones.